# Benders Decomposition for Fixed Charge Transportation Problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, algorithms, benders-decomposition, decomposition

I am trying to write down the steps in Benders decomposition for the Fixed Charge Transportation Problem and was hoping someone could confirm/deny whether my understanding of it is correct. The original problem is
$$
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\begin{align*}
  \min~&\sum_{i\in \mc{I}}\sum_{j\in \mc{J}}c_{ij}x_{ij}+\sum_{i\in \mc{I}}\sum_{j\in \mc{J}}f_{ij}y_{ij}&\\
  \text{s.t.}~&\sum_{j\in \mc{J}}x_{ij} \leq S_i& i\in \mc{I}\\
       &\sum_{i\in \mc{I}}x_{ij} \geq D_j& j\in \mc{J}\\
       &x_{ij}\leq u_{ij}y_{ij}&  i\in\mc{I}, j\in \mc{J}\\
       &y_{ij}\in\{0,1\},x_{ij}\geq 0& i\in \mc{I}, j\in\mc{J}.
\end{align*}
$$
with $u_{ij}=\min(S_i,D_j)$

Now, the $y$ variables are complicating, thus the master problem becomes
$$
\begin{align}
    \min &\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}f_{ij}y_{ij} + \alpha\\
    &y_{i,j}\in \{0,1\}\hspace{25pt} i=1,2,...,I,j=1,2,...,J\\
    &\alpha \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

With the subproblem being
$$
\begin{align}
    \alpha(y) = &\min \sum_{i\in \mc{I}}\sum_{j\in \mc{J}}c_{ij}x_{ij}\\
    &\sum_{j\in \mc{J}}x_{ij} \leq S_i \hspace{25pt} (\tau_i)& i\in \mc{I}\\
    &\sum_{i\in \mc{I}}x_{ij} \geq D_j \hspace{25pt} (\phi_j)& j\in \mc{J}\\
    &x_{ij}\leq u_{ij}y_{ij} \hspace{25pt} (\psi_{ij})&  i\in\mc{I}, j\in \mc{J}\\
    &x_{ij}\geq 0& i\in \mc{I}, j\in\mc{J}
\end{align}
$$

Where I have put in parentheses the dual variables to the constraints. Is it then correct that if the subproblem is infeasible we will add a cut to the master problem that is

$$
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\tau_iS_i + \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\phi_jD_j + \sum_{i\in\mathcal{i}}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\psi_{ij}u_{ij}y_{ij}\leq0
\end{align}
$$

and if it feasible but the solution is not optimal in the original problem, then an optimality cut will be added:
$$
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\tau_iS_i + \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\phi_jD_j + \sum_{i\in\mathcal{i}}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\psi_{ij}u_{ij}y_{ij}\leq\alpha
\end{align}
$$

Am I understanding that right?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this looks correct.  For comparison, check out Erwin Kalvelagen's *[Benders Decomposition with GAMS](https://amsterdamoptimization.com/pdf/benders.pdf)*, which uses an equality-constrained version of this fixed charge transportation problem for illustration.  Note that the equivalent dual LP is solved instead.  Also, he provides two sets of valid constraints on $y$ that you can include a priori to strengthen the master problem:
\begin{align}
\sum_i S_i y_{ij} &\ge D_j &&\text{for all $j$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_j D_j y_{ij} &\ge S_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Note that \eqref{2} assumes $\sum_i S_i = \sum_j D_j$, so omit \eqref{2} if that assumption is violated.